# Comparing two regex objects

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I have two regex values that have been tested and work:

```
(?<=\bpolicy-map\s)(\w+)
```

and

```
(?<=\binput\s)(\w+)
```

I now need to compare the two regex values for a match. 

(?<=\binput\s)(\w+) obtains the word after "service-policy input" while (?<=\bpolicy-map\s)(\w+) obtains the word after "policy-map".
Backstory is that I have a router configs file, and am seeing if the "policy-map" value matches what is in the "service-policy input" value. Below are my values from a router config file I am testing. Note the values will not be consecutive, as "control-plane" sits in-between them so may have to do a (?s) or something:

```
------------rtr config-----------------
policy-map RTR_CoPP
control-plane
service-policy input RTR_CoPP
------------rtr config-----------------
```

Comment: Java and JavaScript are not the same.... what is it...

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking, and what either Java or JavaScript has to do with it.  Are you asking for help writing a regex?  Are you asking for help writing a program?  Any way around, show us what you've done so far to attempt to solve the problem you're asking about.

Comment: (?<=\binput\s)(\w+) obtains the word after "service-policy input" while (?<=\bpolicy-map\s)(\w+) obtains the word after  "policy-map" need to check if both words are the same.

Comment: Ultimately trying to get a simple Regex solution, not write a program. This is for one specific check to ensure that the word after "policy-map" and "service-policy input" are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you're doing is parsing your config which reads the text as a string, 
I would simplify your regex to match the first item: `/^.*policy-map\s(\w+)` and the second item: `/\binput\s(\w+)$/`

This should parse the first regex from the beginning and the second part from the end. If you're comparing the matches from two different regex's you don't need `?=` which resets the pointer if you're inputting into a single regex.

Comment: The purpose was to use a lookbehind to locate the unknown word after the phrase "route-map" and "service-policy input", ensuring they are the same. RTR_CoPP is just one of many names that could exist, since the name of a policy is not constant. I could not get your regex to work, as it matches the entire phrase "policy-map RTR_CoPP" not just the "RTR_CoPP" portion.